# Proper way to specify port for tcp outgoing address Squid

Tags: http, proxy, squid, centos8

I am trying to setup squid in order to route outgoing traffic randomly through different proxies. These are proxies I purchased from a provider, not part of my network. I need to specify a specific port for each IP address in order to connect but can't figure out the correct way to do this. I am on CentOS 8.

I've tried adding them in these ways:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 1.0.0.01:<port>

tcp_outgoing_address 1.0.0.01/<port>

tcp_outgoing_address 1.0.0.01 <port>

tcp_outgoing_address 1.0.0.01 ::<port>
```

Obviously, none of which work and actually prevent squid from starting. I can't seem to find any resources similar to my question online.

The only way I can get squid to start is by omitting the port entirely, like so:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 1.0.0.01
```

However, when I do this, and attempt to access any URL I receive the following squid error in the browser:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://xxxx.com/

Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX failed.

The system returned: [No Error]
```

Likely this is because I am not actually specifying the port that squid needs to connect to each proxy. To clarify, each proxy has a different open port i.e 1.0.0.01:8080, 1.0.0.02:5000 ...

ACL Random bit:

```
acl random1 random 1/10
acl random2 random 1/9
acl random3 random 1/8
acl random4 random 1/7
acl random5 random 1/6
acl random6 random 1/5
acl random7 random 1/4
acl random8 random 1/3
acl random9 random 1/2

tcp_outgoing_address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx random1
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xxx random2
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random3
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random4
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random5
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random6
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random7
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random8
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random9
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx
```

My config file is as follows:

```
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src xx.xx.xx.xxx   # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl client src xx.xx.xx.xxx # Home IP
http_access allow client

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#



# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid



acl random1 random 1/10
acl random2 random 1/9
acl random3 random 1/8
acl random4 random 1/7
acl random5 random 1/6
acl random6 random 1/5
acl random7 random 1/4
acl random8 random 1/3
acl random9 random 1/2

tcp_outgoing_address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx random1
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xxx random2
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random3
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random4
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random5
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random6
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random7
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random8
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx random9
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx

via off
forwarded_for off

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Essentially, my question is how do I specify the port each proxy needs to connect through, or perhaps is this somehow not necessary? If it is not, is there a reason anyone could identify why I am not able to connect to any websites with the port ommited?

Comment: It may be orthogonal to your problem, but my understanding is that for `tcp_outgoing_address` to work, squid had to have been compiled with this setting: `./configure --enable-linux-netfilter`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
http_port 10000
acl port10000 localport 10000
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xx.xx.xx port10000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).